# Another word for someone who follows plans perfectly

Tags: single-word-requests

I mean to use the word in a good sense. To show that the person always adheres to the plans/strategies. Does not deviate even an inch.

I'm not looking for stickler or conformist nor do I mean to use the word in any disparaging way.

e.g. sentence - Joe knew that Michael would begin to see his point of view and he would have to agree to it, albeit reluctantly. After all, that had been the plan all along and he would stick to it. He was a ***phrase here*** all the way through.

Note - I'm ok with slang.

Comment: ***meticulous***, ***punctilious***, ***scrupulous***, ***rigorous***, ***fastidious***, ***methodical***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say that one is "fastidious"

From Marriam-Webster

> showing or demanding excessive delicacy or care
>   fastidious attention to detail — Robert Evett

Also similar would be "meticulous"

> marked by extreme or excessive care in the consideration or treatment of details

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a ***perfectionist***.
(I could think of several adjectives; however, your question indicates that you want a noun).

[From dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perfectionist):

> **perfectionist** *noun*  ​
>
> a person who wants everything to be perfect and demands the highest
> standards possible: She's such a perfectionist that she notices even
> the tiniest mistakes.

Comment: That's the thing, it's not about perfection but about following a strategy always no matter what. It's about picking the optimal path and then sticking to it.

Answer (score 0):

A **proceduralist** is one who advocates *proceduralism* or the rigid adherence to established procedures. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proceduralism))

Answer (score -1):

One might use "austerity" in regards to this person.  The person practiced austerity.  I'm not saying the person was "austerity."  The actions of the person evidenced austerity.

e.g. sentence - Joe knew that Michael would begin to see his point of view and he would have to agree to it, albeit reluctantly. After all, that had been the plan all along and he would stick to it. *It was his austerity here all the way through that ensured the success of Joe's plan.*

Comment: Please refer to a dictionary, then rewrite this answer citing what was found.